# how to select the value of a select dropdown using javascript/angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

this is how i am trying to access the select dropdown and now i want to select the option of which i have a value :

```
var A    
A= document.getElementById("aID");
```

this is the value i am getting while editing a row record using angular JS :

```
$scope.Act[index].ATextValue;
```

and i am trying to get which is wrong but i want the correct solution or way to do this :

```
 document.getElementById("aID").selectedValue=$scope.Act[index].ATextValue;
```

Comment: a simple tutorial for angular drop downs
https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_select.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Using this code

```
<select ng-model="selectedName" >
   <option ng-repeat="x in names" ng-value="x">{{x}}</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve but here is a sample snippet on implementing a simple dropdown select.

HTML for Dropdown:

```
<select ng-model="selectedName" ng-change="ShowSelectedValue()"
        ng-options="x for x in names">
```

Angularjs:

```
// Dropdown Items
$scope.names = ["a", "b", "c"];

// When an item is selected, an alert is displayed
// $scope.selectedName will be the container of the selected value
$scope.ShowSelectedValue = function (){
  alert($scope.selectedName);
}
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: i have to edit one row data and on clicking the row button i am trying to get the data into the form which has select and i dont know how to select the value according to the data in the row

Comment: @BKM show your code for me to fully understand your problem. Thank you

Comment: i just want to select the option which has the value i got from clicking on get details of a record so for example 
i got a dropdown of fruits and the record has apple then apple should be selected or if i have the value orange then option orange should be selected